# Highcharts, bar chart, change bar color on hover?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using the states.hover property on a bar chart, there does not seem to be a direct way to change the color of the hovered bar.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.states.hover

Is there a work around for this?

Seems very odd to be able to update the "brightness", but not just be able to directly specify a hover state fill color...

{{**EDIT**

Ok, so, the hover.color works if no color is explicitly set on the bar, but does not if the color is set at the point level (ie '`{y:8, color:'#00ff00'}`').

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3qtZr/44/

I have a chart where I need to set some colors explicitly on the point level, but still want to override the color on hover.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle provided by the API as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/halo/

Comment: that lists the halo option...?

Comment: @jlbriggs you fiddle works fine.

Comment: hover over the top, green, bar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is color property.

```
 states: {
          hover: {
                 brightness: 0.2,
                 color: '#ffccee'
                    }
}
```

Comment: very odd. it isn't working on my current chart, and when I saw it wasn't listed as an option in the docs, I assumed that was why. Now I have to figure out why it's not working for me...

Comment: @jlbriggs check the console for errors, maybe there's some typo.

Comment: No errors. Please see updated question - problem is setting original color at point level (which I need to do). Any thoughts?

Comment: @jlbriggs do you want the HOVER color for each data to be different ?

Comment: No, I need some individually colored bars, but all with the same hover color.

Comment: @jlbriggs you can set it explicitly, check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3qtZr/45/

Comment: Well that's not as convenient as I was hoping for... But it will work - thank you!

Comment: This is correct but the only issue is to provide it within series attribute along data

Answer (score 0):

Simply Provide it in the configure obj

```
    series: [
        {
            //data
            states: {
                hover: {
                    brightness: 0.5,
                    color: '#4318FF'
                }
            },
        }
    ],
```